# Do I need to take Advanced Courses for Trade School, and specifically for plumbing? (Specific Questions enclosed)

Tags: career-path

I have a quick question. I'm a sophomore in high school, and I wanted to go to trade school after I graduate. I had some questions about what courses to take for trade school, and specifically for plumbing.

1. I'm in English 2 Honors, and I was wondering if I should take English 3 or AP Lang.
2. I'm in Spanish 2 Honors, and I was wondering if I should skip Spanish 3 Honors and take Spanish 4 Honors; that way I can take AP Spanish in my Senior Year, or if I should just take Spanish 3 Honors.

P.S. Is SAT/ACT really necessary for trade school?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is off topic for this site.  A high school guidance counselor would likely be more familiar with trade schools and can help you prepare for them.

Comment: Undergraduate admissions is off topic here. These would be great questions for a counselor at your school.